# How to execute gdb script in eclipse when it attached?

Tags: eclipse, gdb

I usually run a load libraries script when I attached to a process when I using eclipse.
I what it run this script automatically after I just attached to the process. But the .gdbinit script is executed at the beginning of attaching. Thus load libraries will fail in the .gdbinit script.
Is there a "ON_ATTACHED" function to let me do that?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in another of my questions, I can write a .gdbinit script and define a post_run command.

[How to redefine a gdb built-in command and call and call the original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108321/how-to-redefine-a-gdb-built-in-command-and-call-the-original)