# How to redefine a gdb built-in command and call the original

Tags: debugging, gdb

I redefined a built-in command in gdb, for example "run", I want to do printing a message and then call the original "run" command to execute the real function.
If I write like this:

```
define run
   print "running"
   run
end
```

The gdb will reach the max execute limitation, because it is calling recursively. How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gdb [User-defined Command Hooks](http://sources.redhat.com/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html#Hooks). For example this hook will print message before `run` command:

```
define hook-run
print "running"
end
```